# Hi guys! simple error with AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I created a User model in apps.accounts.models,

added it to installed_apps

specified it as AUTH_USER_MODEL

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apps.accounts'
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

and got an error

**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'accounts.User' that has not been installed**

this is probably due to the fact that accounts has not been registered, but

When I write

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'apps.accounts.User'
```

I get an error

**line 15, in make_model_tuple
app_label, model_name = model.split(".")**

**ValueError: Invalid model reference 'apps.accounts.User'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.**

what should I do with this?

if I enter from the app. then I get the error "split",

if I don't drive apps. then I get the error "that has not been installed"

any hint will be appreciated

Comment: What does the `AppConfig` of your `apps.accounts` looks like?

Comment: from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.accounts'. @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 2):

why not try this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts'
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

and I think your `AppConfig` should look like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'accounts'
```